# Textfield and SQL in Jetpack Compose (Kotlin)

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I'm trying to save the data of a few textfields in an SQL-database and load the data back into the textfields when starting the app again. So far, these two things work, but loading the data into the textfields prevents the user from entering any new content into the textfields.
I guess, that has something to do with the state. Any idea, what I might be missing?

````
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    val context = this
    var db = DataBaseHandler(context)

    var initialload : Boolean = true
    var name = " "
    var number = " "

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        callData()

        setContent {
            BackgroundLocationTrackingTheme {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(32.dp)
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
                ) {

                    // var name by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                    TextField(
                        value = name,
                        onValueChange = { name = it },
                        label = { Text("Name") }
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

                    // var number by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                    TextField(
                        value = number,
                        onValueChange = { number = it },
                        label = { Text("Your phone number") },
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

                    Button(onClick = {
                        if(name.toString().length > 0 &&
                            number.toString().length > 0) {
                            var user = User(name.toString(),number.toString().toInt())

                            db.insertData(user)
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill in all data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Save")
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        // callData()
    }

    fun callData(){
        // Toast.makeText(context, initialload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if(initialload == true) {
            var data = db.readData()

            dataname = data.get(0).name.toString()
            datanumber = data.get(0).number.toString()

            initialload = false
            // Toast.makeText(context, "initialload is false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {}

    }

}```


The problem seems to be the combination of callData() and the textfields themselves. When I don't use callData(), writing into the texfields works fine. Without the textfields of Jetpack Compose the app also works fine.
````

Answer (score 0):

Compose doesn't know about the change, you need some observable value holder like `Flow` or `State`. This should do the trick:

```
var name by mutableStateOf("")
var number by mutableStateOf("")
```